# Can't specialize template member function to std::string

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve. I have the following header file:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo() {}
        ~Foo() {}

        template<typename T>
        T bar()
        {
            T var1 {65};
            T var2 {66};
            return var1 + var2;
        }
};
```

If I run the following main.cpp

```
    printf("%d\n", f.bar<int>());
    printf("%f\n", f.bar<float>());
    printf("%s\n", f.bar<std::string>().c_str());
```

I get this result, as expected:

```
131
131.000000
AB
```

Suppose I want to specialize the case with std::string. I first try to do this:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo() {}
        ~Foo() {}

        template<typename T>
        T bar()
        {
            T var1 {65};
            T var2 {66};
            return var1 + var2;
        }

        template<>
        std::string bar()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
};
```

But the compiler is not happy and says "error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class Foo'". Ok fine, I remove it from the header file and put it in a cpp file, like this:

```
    template<>
    std::string Foo::bar()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
```

This time the compiler is happy but when I run the program I get the same output and the std::string specialization is not picked up. I expect the main to return this instead:

```
131
131.000000
Hello
```

Does anyone know what's happening here? In particular, why can't I declare the specialization in the header file? And why doesn't the specialization in the cpp file work? What am I missing?

I'm using gcc version 8.5.0

Thanks

Comment: It works as you expect in clang 16.0.0: https://godbolt.org/z/a773bbKb6
But fails to compile with "error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class Foo'" in gcc 8.5.0. You can move specialization out of class, so it works in both: https://godbolt.org/z/Ed3EEMTz6

Comment: So is this a bug in gcc?

Comment: I really don't know, but my guess is that it is clang's extension or newer language feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler needs to see the specialization in order to use it, so put it in the header but outside of the class definition.

Comment: It works if I declare it outside the class and define it in the cpp file. I wonder why it has to be that way though, namely why I get that compilation error if it's defined within the class.